# ng-bind-html and unsafe not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following version of Angularjs and trying to bind property called Description, that containing html tags, with my template. 
I tried to use
`{{Description | unsafe}}` -- rendering html as string
`ng-bind-html-unsafe` -- nothing rendering
`ng-bind-html` -- nothing rendering

Files:

```
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vendortoolkit/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vendortoolkit/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

How html string can be rendered as html?

Comment: It will more helpful to you if you can share the problem with the view and js file. OR Make jsfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `$sce` service. Inject `$sce` to your controller & then use `trustAsHtml` method. In controller add code as:

```
$scope.desc = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.Description);
```

Where `$scope.Description` is a string containing html tags

Then, bind on template with `ng-bind-html` :

```
<div ng-bind-html="desc"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For ng-bind-html to work as expected, you need to include angular-sanitize library and ngSanitize as a dependency injection.
Sharing here an example for the same. Hope, this helps.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "My name is: <h1>John Doe</h1>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>
```